# Severe discharge of 12 v battery

Tags: discharge

I have 2 Trojan T105 6 volt batteries that are 3 months old connected in series for 12 volts. I inadvertently discharged them to 4 volts(!) by leaving an inverter turned on without anything drawing off it,(it takes .26 amps just on) and not having my battery charger turned on. When I went to the boat and discovered they were at 4 volts, I turned the charger on, and they took a charge. They seem to be holding it, but I'm concerned. What damage might I have done to the batteries? Any thoughts???

Comment: What as google told you? Have you done any research?

Comment: laptop- yea, I did some research on Google. There was nothing on severe discharge(4volts), but a lot of info on just discharging to 10.5 volts. That's why I chose to ask here

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your batteries are so called Lead acid batteries and if you keep them long uncharged below 40% you come into the danger zone. Below 20% charge you can loose capacity.

Here is why:

During the discharge the active mass of the battery changes from lead dioxide and spongy lead into lead sulfate. This lead sulfate has a fine structure and returns during the charge back to lead dioxide and spongy lead.

If now during a deep discharge the recharge does not take place in time (to late) the lead sulfate starts to crystallize thereby forming large crystals. These crystals block the pories of the active mass and form a barrier over the plate surface making it impossible to charge the battery. The result is sulfatation and permanent loss of capacity.

Therefore if the batteries did not remain to long in an uncharged situation the damage could be small to nothing. If it it took a long time before recharging you could end up with permanent damage to the battery. You might have been lucky.

Comment: There has been a downvote on my answer. I would appreciate to know why?

Comment: Decapod- Don't know. Wasn't me. I don't know enough about batteries to disagree with what you said... some people are like that.